# Adobe Livecycle Designer 7 Text Field Issue

Tags: livecycle-designer

I have a form in a large box, to be filled in by the user with up to 2500 characters.  Currently, the cursor starts in the vertical center of the box and I would like:

a) The cursor to start at the top left of the field instead of the middle left, so that there is no whitespace above the user's entered text.

or b) Somehow enabling a field that expands to fit its text to expand **as the text is being entered.**  As far as I can tell, text fields set to expand to fit the text inside only expand once the user has taken their cursor off the field.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the field and go to "Palletes". Click "Paragraph".  This will give you the paragraph/text alignment controls in your rightside toolbar.

Alternately, you can click "Window" at the top and choose "Paragraph" from there (Shortcut is Shift+F5).